# I cant copying datetime to another datetime table with SQL Ce

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Im trying to copy the datetime (`FECHA`) to another table with datetime format, but sql says "problem in date format (`FECHA`)". Any idea?

SQL have a `DATEFORMAT` function, but in SQL Ce, dont exists... :(

My query;

```
INSERT RESUMEN (FECHA,ARTICULO,METROS) 
SELECT ARTICULO, FECHA, Sum(METROS) as Cant 
FROM HISTORIC 
WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '07/08/2016' AND '07/12/2016' 
GROUP BY ARTICULO,FECHA.
```

If I do this query WORKS, but with no `datetime` in the column `FECHA`;

```
INSERT RESUMEN (ARTICULO,METROS) 
SELECT ARTICULO, Sum(METROS) as Cant 
FROM HISTORIC 
WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '07/08/2016' AND '07/12/2016' 
GROUP BY ARTICULO
```

Comment: Hola Rock. The correct spelling is *With*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column order of your inserts appear to be backwards:

```
INSERT RESUMEN (FECHA,ARTICULO,METROS) 
SELECT ARTICULO,FECHA, Sum(METROS) as Cant 
FROM HISTORIC 
WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '07/08/2016' AND '07/12/2016' 
GROUP BY ARTICULO,FECHA
```

You are inserting `ARTICULO` in the `FECHA` column.  Switch these two fields:

```
INSERT RESUMEN (FECHA,ARTICULO,METROS) 
SELECT FECHA, ARTICULO, Sum(METROS) as Cant 
FROM HISTORIC 
WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '07/08/2016' AND '07/12/2016' 
GROUP BY ARTICULO,FECHA
```

Comment: Yeah. Thats it! What a stupid error hehe. Thank you a lot!